# Probability of averages

Tags: probability, random-variable, central-limit-theorem

I have a random variable $Y$ and I am taking an independent sample of $n$ from this RV.

I'll refer to this sample as $Y_n$, and I define the average of this sample as $\bar{Y}_n$. The maximum of this sample is similarly $\max(Y_n)$.

Since $Y$ is derived from population data, I'll also define the 95<sup>th</sup> percentile of the data source as $Y_{\{0.95\}}$ (not the percentile of the *sample*)

Assuming by the CLT that $\bar{Y}_n \sim N(\mu,\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})$, is there a simple way to find
$$
P\left(\max(Y_n) > Y_{\{0.95\}} \;|\;\bar{Y}_n > z\right)?
$$

That is, what is the probability that the maximum of a *sample* or size $n$ is greater than the 95<sup>th</sup> percentile of the *population*, given that the average of that sample is higher than a given value.

Edit: added some clarification on terms.

Comment: Does $Y_{\{0.95\}}$ depend on $Y_1,...Y_n$ or is it the theoretical value calculated from pdf/pmf of $Y$. Also, does $\max(Y_n)$ mean the max of $Y_1,...,Y_n$?

Comment: @gunes, $Y$ is derived from data, so $Y_{\{0.95\}}$ is the 95th percentile of that data source. $Y$ is the assumed underlying distribution of that data. $\max(Y_n)$ is indeed the maximum of the $Y_1, Y_2,...,Y_n$. Sorry for the ambiguous notation.

Comment: How can the 95th percentile of a sample exceed it's maximum?

Comment: It's the 95th percentile of the population data. $Y_n$ is the sample of size $n$, and so $\max(Y_n)$ is the maximum of that _sample_

Comment: Hint: the event $\max(Y_n)\gt Y_q$ means it is not the case that all the values in the sample are less than $Y_q.$ To proceed further, you need to tell us what kind of sample this is.  In particular, are its values *independent?*

Comment: @whuber Yes, samples are independent. I attempted to rearrange using Bayes Thereom, but it didn't seem to make it much easier. The RV, Y can also be assumed to be logNormal as the distribution of the data is close to this.

Comment: By definition of the quantile (at least for continuous random variables), $q$ is the chance that $Y\lt Y_q.$ By the definition of independence, these chances multiply.  Done.

Comment: @whuber. So that gets me to $1- P(Y < Y_{\{0.95\}} | \bar{Y}_n > z)^n$. How do you take into account the $\bar{Y}_n > z$ part?

Comment: In my haste I didn't originally catch the conditional requirement. Evaluating that probability requires finding the joint distribution of the max and mean, which comes down to the joint distribution between the max and each of the values. Although there may be some shortcuts available for finding expectations with small $n$ (up to about $5,$ as I recall, owing to the symmetry of the Normal distribution), generally this requires numerical integration.

Comment: Upon re-reading, I am also reminded you are invoking the CLT.  That won't work for this problem, because the CLT tells you nothing at all about the maximum.  You can't make progress without invoking a strong distributional assumption or by accepting bounds on the probability (bounds that may be very weak if they are to hold generally).  As a simple example, the probability you ask about is always zero when $Y$ has a Bernoulli$(1/2)$ distribution, no matter what $z$ may be.